# SQL - Order by with alphanumeric characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following table:

```
create table #tbl
(
 product_id nvarchar(50)
)

insert into #tbl values ('011014-A11')
insert into #tbl values ('011014-A10')
insert into #tbl values ('011014')
insert into #tbl values ('011014-A1')
insert into #tbl values ('011014-A2')
```

I want to order the Product IDs like this (from the smallest to the greatest):

```
011014
011014-A1
011014-A2
011014-A10
011014-A11
```

This is what I tried, but it is not working:

```
select product_id
from #tbl
order by product_id desc
```

How do I do this?
And how do I get just the greatest product_id?
I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
select top 1 product_id
from #tbl
order by product_id desc
```

Comment: What do you mean by greatest product_id? Which product_Id you need?

Comment: please let us know the format of the product_id as well

Comment: Where would `011014-B1` go?  I assume after all of the `A`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query to get the results in your expected order.

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e01ce/4)**

```
Select product_id
From tbl              --Please change table name to #tbl in your actual query
Order by len(product_id), product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already accepted Kaf's answer, and it may work well for you, but it will only work *as long as the first 8 characters are the same*.  For example if you added a value of `011014-B1` then your results would be:

```
011014
011014-A1
011014-A2
011014-B1
011014-A10
011014-A11
```

If your pattern is consistent (sort by the first8 chars then by the "number" after them, this may work better for you:

```
Select product_id
From #tbl              
Order by LEFT(product_id,8), CAST(SUBSTRING(product_id,9,9) AS INT)
```

Comment: `CAST(SUBSTRING(product_id,9,99) AS INT)` ?  How do you fit 99 digits into an int?

Comment: @Anon you don't - I just use that as quick "give be everything from here to the end" since SQL's `SUBSTRING` doesn't support an optional `length` parameter.